# Joomla 2.5 Module - Ajax call to self returns invalid token

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla2.5, token

I'm writing a php code inside a module (with sourcerer plugin) that takes a URL from a form input and (with ajax) parse it and returns some values.
To parse the HTML i use SimpleHTMLdom (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
include_once('simpledom/simple_html_dom.php');

if ($_GET["fld1"]){
$url_to_parse = $_GET["fld1"];
$html = file_get_html($url_to_parse);
$titolo = $html->find('header.rHeader h1');
$es = $html->find('dd.ingredient a');
/* here I get all the ingredients for the recipe URL and return them */
foreach($es as $es_element){ 
    echo "<item>".$es_element->plaintext."</item>&nbsp;";
    }
}
?>
```

and here is the HTML/JS code that calls the PHP with AJAX:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: location.href,
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML = data;
                    document.getElementById('showcomments').style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="form" method="post">
    <!-- this php returns an hiddn input with my token=1 -->
    <?php echo JHtml::_( 'form.token' ); ?>
    <!-- in this input I have to insert a URL like this: http://ricette.giallozafferano.it/Girandole-alle-fragole.html -->
    <input type="text" name="fld1" id="fld1" size="90" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>

<div id="showcomments" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <h2>I have found your recipe:</h2>
    <div id="comments"></div>
</div>
```

If you put all this code inside a php file it runs smoothly. If I wirte it in a module and then load inside a joomla page i get an "invalid token" error.

I know I have to handle the tokens working with joomla but i don't know how to handle this situation.. Is this errore caused by a call to self? Do I have to call an external PHP page or a component?

Thank you